# Archimate - Application Layer - Interfaces + Database

Tags: enterprise-architect, archimate

I am quite new to the Achrimate 3.0 and I am trying to make my model in it. I put an example below. My goal is to model this stream of data where I have a Source System which is creating output files in specific format -> next Step is Pulling the data by processing component and looking for some values in connected DB -> final step is then deliver this data (pushed by processing component) to Target Systems.

Q1: What relationship is correct to Application Component and Interface? In the picture is triggering (but maybe FLOW fits better) ?

Q2: Database is joined via Access relationship ?

Q3: For my purposes it will need to hold information about DB (columns+types+notes) structure in the diagram, any tips, how to manage it in Archimate ?

Diagram Example Here:

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Archimate. But on Sparx' forum there are a couple of heavy users. You might cross-post and link to this (they don't support pictures).

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be nice to read the specification (http://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/archimate3-doc/chap09.html#_Toc489946063).

Are you sure that you use only application layer? If so, then the interface is not defined correctly, the interface that you specified is rather related to the technology layer.

So:

1. Wrong interface (IMHO). Figure 67: Application Layer Metamodel of spec show you how elements can be linked on this layer.
2. Database can be represent as component, not DataObject.
3. In my experience - no good way. Use the standard reverse engineering mechanism. Associate the resulting UML objects with the Archimate elements if you need it.